# Javascript - Eventlistener function not working, toggle opacity on click

Tags: javascript, html, function

In the box I want it to say Hi, but when you click on the div "hi" it will instead toggle the div with "bye" using opacity. My design is not actually with text but svg paths, so this was the best way to translate what I need help with, without having to much code in the snippet (as the svg is quite a lot of code). However, when I click on "hi" nothing happens. What can I change to fix this?

As I am not very experienced with javascript, I am asking you for help to make this function actually work.

```js
const Fana = document.getElementById("Fana")

Fana.addEventListener("onclick", FanaFunction());

function FanaFunction() {
  if (clicked = true) {
    document.getElementById("Fana").style.opacity = "0";
    document.getElementById("Fana-H").style.opacity = "1";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("Fana").style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById("Fana-H").style.opacity = "0";
  } else if {
    document.getElementById("Fana").style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById("Fana-H").style.opacity = "0";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.box-test {
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 3px red;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: white;
}

#Fana {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#Fana-H {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-test">
  <div id="Fana">hi</div>
  <div id="Fana-H">bye</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Start by removing the () from `Fana.addEventListener("onclick", FanaFunction());`

Comment: `clicked = true` is assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**else if** must be use befor of **else**!!! and else if need to () and condation.
when use if must == or === this  **if (clicked = true)** is not true code.

I fixed your code:

```
const Fana = document.getElementById("Fana")
let clicked = true;
Fana.addEventListener("click", FanaFunction);

function FanaFunction() {
  if (clicked ) {
    document.getElementById("Fana").style.opacity = "0";
    document.getElementById("Fana-H").style.opacity = "1";
    clicked =false
  } else {
    document.getElementById("Fana").style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById("Fana-H").style.opacity = "0";
    clicked=true;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There were more than one issues with your code. I'm sharing working solution below.

1. Your code had problem with event assignment, you shouldn't use parenthesis just pass the function.
2. When you use `else if` you have to add a condition just like `if`.
3. `clicked = true` is not a condition is an assignment. You should use double (or triple, strict equality) equal operator. Also it wasn't declared anywhere.

```js
let sayingHi = true;
const Fana = document.getElementById("Fana")
Fana.addEventListener("click", FanaFunction);

function FanaFunction() {
  if (sayingHi) {
    document.getElementById("Fana").style.opacity = "0";
    document.getElementById("Fana-H").style.opacity = "1";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("Fana").style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById("Fana-H").style.opacity = "0";
  }
  
  sayingHi = !sayingHi;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.box-test {
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 3px red;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: white;
}

#Fana {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#Fana-H {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-test">
  <div id="Fana">hi</div>
  <div id="Fana-H">bye</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has problem in event name. It should be **"click"** instead of **"onclick"**.

Moreover, when you passing function to event listener, you need to pass as function without calling it. Here, you called **FanaFunction()** when you passing. That will not pass a Function instead it'll pass only return value of that function. So, you've to pass as **FanaFunction**.

I think **"else"** and **"else if"** part is just a typo.

I attached the code in one format. So, you can see easily with copy paste. Moreover, you need to use some postion css properties to overlap between those two. Currently, I saw that bye is still showing in below of hi as a blank one.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    body {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: black;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 2em;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
    .box-test {
        text-align: center;
        border: solid 3px red;
        width: 400px;
        background-color: white;
    }
    

    #Fana {
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
    #Fana-H {
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="box-test">
    <div id="Fana">hi</div>
    <div id="Fana-H">bye</div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    const Fana = document.getElementById("Fana")

    Fana.addEventListener("click", FanaFunction);

    function FanaFunction() {
       if (clicked = true) {
        document.getElementById("Fana").style.opacity = "0";
        document.getElementById("Fana-H").style.opacity = "1";
       } else {
        document.getElementById("Fana").style.opacity = "1";
        document.getElementById("Fana-H").style.opacity = "0";
       } 
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```